# Vue Convert Unicode to HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, api, unicode, vuejs2

I'm calling an API that returns a Unicode string as follows.

When I output this in the view it does not automatically convert those characters to HTML for rendering but I think Vue treats it as a string. As far as I know, Javascript should render it.

I have tried using the **v-html** directive to no avail.

Is there any way I can tell Vue not to output the data as a string?

**UPDATE**
I'm using this function to convert Unicode to text:

```
unicodeToText: function(string) {
  var b = "\\\\u"
  return string.replace(new RegExp(b + "([0-9a-fA-F]{4})", "g"), function(c, d) {
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(d, 16))
  })
}
```

Both of the below are the exact same string.

```
this.homeText = this.unicodeToText(response.data.text);
```

However, when I use the v-html directive, the API string returns:

The hard-coded string returns it perfectly like so:

Comment: Refer this [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/escape-html-characters-with-vuejs?page=1](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/escape-html-characters-with-vuejs?page=1)

Comment: @Thennarasan I don't think this is relevant. I'm trying to convert unicode.

Comment: Hope you are want to load the data that you got to the view as HTML. If you just do a console.log({data that you have posted})  it will print the html. So where ever you want to show up, you can just use the selector and use .html({pass the data}) it will load the html.

Comment: @Thennarasan html() is a method of jQuery, which I'm not using.

Comment: Try running this fiddle, i have used your data.
[http://jsfiddle.net/qw5dj0md/](http://jsfiddle.net/qw5dj0md/)

Comment: @Thennarasan thank you for that. I updated the question. With a hard-coded string it also works for me, but the returned data doesn't work as you can see in the screenshot. Both strings are the same.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen can you give the dummy API link so that we can simulate the issue

Comment: @rummykhan http://surebuddy.azurewebsites.net/Api/Contents?country=ZA - Authorization: 'Basic c3VyZWJ1ZGR5LWFwaS11c2VyOkFwaTQzMjJTdXJlYg=='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon checking the response, I found text is a unicode string. 
To convert back to normal text pass it through `JSON.parse( text )`.

```
decodeData(data){
    return JSON.parse('"' + data + '"');
}
```

Here is working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rummykhan/gevbqk7f/19/).

[JSON.parse() Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)